# h1 tag not changing color with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't see any reason why my style.css file isn't overriding bootstrap here - the h1 tag isn't changing to white. 
The stylesheet is below bootstrap, and unless there's something about the jumbotron I don't know I'm not quite sure what the problem could be...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Raphael Hetherington</title>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="back1">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>My First Page</h1>
            <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
            <span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Clients</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="base.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and CSS:

```
h1 {
    color: white;
}

#back1 {
    background-image: url("images/tiger.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.jumbotron{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: h1 {
    color: white !important;
}

Comment: Did you try to inspect your page to see what is happening here ?

Comment: yeah use !important to override bootstrap code.

Comment: Avoid `!important` whenever possible. Why are you including Bootstrap's CSS twice?

Answer (score 2):

Even though your CSS is loaded after Bootstrap's, the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of Bootstrap's selector (`.jumbotron h1`) is higher than yours (`h1`), and it overrides your rule. Simply change your selector to:

```
.jumbotron h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

Avoid using `!important` as some users suggested as it's [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css), can cause problems, and difficult to debug.

**[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/C3XBEvHmtz)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the color on your `css` file

```
   h1 { 
    color: white !important; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using h1 {color: white !important;}

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
#back1 h1{ 
    color: white; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a selector with the highest CSS specificity try using

```
#back1 .container h1{
color:white;
}
```

and see what happens. Also, you are loading the same CSS file twice, which is a little unneeded. I tried testing your code with just the bootstrap css and the content in the `<h1>` tag was white, so try looking at your style.css sheet as see if there are any `!important` that are messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#back1 h1 {
    color: white !important;
}

#back1 {
    background-image: url("images/tiger.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.jumbotron{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Raphael Hetherington</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="back1">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>My First Page</h1>
            <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
            <span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Clients</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
       <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

look this one.